# how fast is digital modulator

Tags: wireless

There are plenty of I/Q modulators produced, how can I learn theirs sample rate(bit rate) from datasheets. There are only LO frequencies and sometimes baseband frequency there.
[For instance](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/ADL5386.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

On p. 5 of the datasheet you linked:

[image]

The bit rate you can transmit with 700 MHz bandwidth depends on the signal-to-noise ratio of your system, according to [Shannon's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem). To achieve the optimum bit rate, you will need to choose a coding scheme appropriate for the noise spectrum of your system.